# stack.clear() faster or popping each element faster?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, stack

Similarly, to find the no of elements in a stack, is `stack.size()` call faster than popping each element and counting? Of course I don't need the stack anymore.

Comment: Please consider the idea that the authors of the Stack class in the JVM know what they are doing. If popping all elements from a stack was for some reason faster than some other implementation of clear(), they would have reimplemented clear() to work by popping all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the implementation of the `Stack` class, but logically popping `n` times cannot be faster than obtaining `count` and calling `clear`: it is an O(n) algorithm.

Obtaining `count`, on the other hand, could be faster, because it can be done in a single access if `Stack` stores the number of items that it has, making it an O(1)<sup>*</sup> algorithm. Similarly, clearing the whole content in one go can be implemented as an O(1).

<sup>*</sup> O(1) is a fancy way of saying "does not depend on the number of elements on the stack".

Comment: It's worth noting that the `clear` can probably only be O(1) if the stack uses a linked-list-type structure internally. If it uses an array (as `java.util.Stack` does, for instance), then you still need to either do an O(n) nulling out of the array elements or an O(n) allocation of a new array. If you kept the underlying array unchanged and just set the counter to 0, you'd have a memory leak (previously held objects would still be referenced by the stack, and thus would be ineligible for GC). That said, the coefficient on those O(n) operations could be significantly different.

Comment: @yshavit Another option is for the `Stack` to simply create a new array of the same capacity and set `size` to 0, leaving the old array to get garbage collected (along with the references in that old array). That being said, the linked list implementation you mentioned is much more memory efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`Stack` inherits from `Vector`, and `Vector` is the class that defines the `size()` method, not Stack. `Vector` also has a protected field called `elementCount`, which is the number of valid elements in the `Vector`. I would assume that the `size()` method just returns this variable, making it much faster to call `size()` than to pop and count. Also, Vector has no need to do pops to count elements because popping is not a feature of Vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can write two functions and test your problem with those functions, you'll learn and figure out your question. Write one function popping each element, pushing it in another stack, and when finished push it all back in the original array (you want to keep the integrity of your stack when calling `.size()`, the size call should not modify your stack). The other with `stack.size()`. Then call each function in your main function and use a function like time() before and after each of the two function calls. You'll see a difference in time between the two functions. Just try it out!

Of course this depends on the implementation of the stack as mentioned in other answers. Just read the documentation of the stack interface and it should be in there.